# SqlAlchemy ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE for bulk upsert

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm confused about the syntax for SqlAlchemy's ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.

I've tried to adapt the example in link below, also studying the documentation for [insert](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mysql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.insert) specifically.

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mysql.html#insert-on-duplicate-key-update-upsert

My code is the following:

```
class GivenName(Base):
# ORM table definition
    __tablename__ = 'given_name'
    given_company_name = Column(String(255), index=True, primary_key=True)
    given_company_name_trimmed = Column(String(255), index=True)
    given_org_number = Column(String(255))
    given_clean_org_number = Column(BigInteger, index=True, primary_key=True)

# two rows to be inserted in json format
insertion_as_dict = [{'given_clean_org_number': 0.0,
                      'given_company_name': 'staby gårdshotell',
                      'given_company_name_trimmed': 'staby gardshotell',
                      'given_org_number': None},
                     {'given_clean_org_number': 5568978430.0,
                      'given_company_name': 'staccato etg ab',
                      'given_company_name_trimmed': 'staccato etg',
                      'given_org_number': 5568978430.0}]

# insertion statement adapted from the sqlalchemy example in link above
insert_stmt = insert(GivenName).values(insertion_as_dict)

on_duplicate_key_stmt = insert_stmt.on_duplicate_key_update(
    values=insert_stmt.inserted
)
session = session_factory()
session.execute(on_duplicate_key_stmt)
session.close()
```

For some reason this produces the error:

```
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1")
```

I don't know if I'm missing something in the description which only seems to demo a one record insertion. They explicitly set the key worded arguments id and data. Is this supposed to correspond to columns in the database or are these api keywords?

Comment: Have you tried to print the statement and see what’s wrong in it?